# purge "DeletedDatabaseRecords" from database

Tags: acumatica

I recently was asked by one of my Customers if there was a method to clean out records with the "DeletedDatabaseRecord" flagged.

They are in the process of implementing a new base company and have done several import/delete/import/delete of key records which has resulted in quite a few of these that they'd prefer not carry over to their actual live company.

Looking through the system i didn't see a build in method to clear these records out.

Is there a method of purging these records that is part of the system, be it from the ERP Configuration tools, stored procedures, or in the interface itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jeff,

No, there is no special functionality to remove records flagged as `DeletedDatabaseRecord`, but you may always use a simple SQL script to loop over all the tables that have this column and remove from each of them the records that have it set to `1`.

Comment: Thanks Alex.  I'll script something up for him to do it.